# a signal x(n) then is this concept of shirting and folding correct?

Tags: signal-processing

x(n) is given

need  x(-n+3)

so to solve it:

- first advance the x(n) signal by 3 units(time)
- then fold it, or make a reflection of it

are the above steps correct or is the following correct

- first fold the x(n) signal
- then advance the signal by 3 units

?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect that this is off topic on Stack Overflow. It doesn't seem to be a question with a programming answer. You may be interested in the proposed Stack Exchange site [Signal Processing ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1691/signal-processing), but unfortunately they are not open for business yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a common source of confusion when learning about signals. Here's what I usually do.

Let `y[n] = x[-n+3]`. Because of `-n`, `y[n]` is obviously a time-reversed version of `x[n]`. But the question about the *shift* remains.

Notice that `y[3] = x[0]`. Therefore, `y[n]` is achieved by first reflecting `x[n]` about `n=0` and then delaying the reflected signal by 3.

For example, let `x[n]` be the unit step function `u[n]`. Draw `x[n]`, then draw `y[n]`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually here is what I do:

Let

```
x(n) = {1,-1,2,4,-3,0,6,-3,-1,2,7,9,-7,5}
                      ^
```

Suppose origin or `n=0` is 6. Note that the `^` symbol indicates the origin. First, we find the folder sequence of `x(-n)` from `x(n)`. So first we fold or we can say reverse the form of `x(n)`, we get,

The folder sequence of `x(-n)` from `x(n)` is

```
x(-n) = {5,-7,9,7,2,-1,-3,6,0,-3,4,2,-1,1}
                          ^
```

then shift the sequence of `x(-n)` towards right hand side by 3 units, we will get

```
x(-n+3) = {5,-7,9,7,2-1,-3,6,0,-3,4,2,-1,1}
                                  ^
```

Now, the sample 4 is at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Above steps are correct.
The following steps can be corrected too if these are followed like:
first fold the x(n) signal
then delay the signal by 3 units this will yield x(-n+3).